# I cant take percent of any value of numbers in jtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, calculator

I'm trying to take %2 of anytypes of value in jtextfield. But when i press the button, it's giving me result "0" . Always 0. Can somone help me ?

```
try{
    int num1=Integer.parseInt(jTextField6.getText());

    int result=num1%2;
    jTextField15.setText(""+result);        

} catch(NumberFormatException e) {

}
```

Comment: It can't be always zero. It would be zero only for even values.

Comment: what do you insert in your textfield?

Comment: check what is the value of 'num1'. Also make sure that no NumberFormatException is not occuring. You should handle it if it happens so.

Comment: Are you sure you are not misunderstanding Modulo(%) to percentage.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BcsHwg4.png Here's the ss , yes . It's always zero rohit. I'm inserting random values. @Suji No error occuring in the panel i can see.

Comment: Guys i tried to multiplicate with 0,02 but , before the running program; code lane giving this error:identifier expeckted . Here 's my code; int result=num1*0,02;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What result do you get when you insert odd value? As you are using Modulo, you will get 0 for all numbers that can be divided by 2 without the remainder after division (all even values) and 1 for the rest.

Comment: i tried to multiplicate with 0,02 but , before the running program; code lane giving this error:identifier expeckted . Here 's my code; int result=num1*0,02;

Comment: What exactly do you need to achieve? If you want 2 percent of original value, I suggest you use decimal type(float or double).
Something like:
float result = num1 * 0.02;

Answer (score 1):

```
int result=num1%2;
```

this will calculate remainder of the num1 and will store it in result variable.....in this case result will always get 1 for odd numbers and 0 for even numbers, because even numbers are fully divisible by 2

here is an example....

```
8%2 = 0
3&2 = 1
4%2 = 0
```

hope you get it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting . I got an idea but it's giving error. I tried to multiplicate it with 0,02. code lane giving this error:identifier expeckted . Here 's my code; int result=num1*0,02

Comment: it is giving error because you are putting a comma(,) instead a dot(.) in 0,02 
try to do it as follows

int result=num1*0.02